# Прибавить или вычесть из time() секунды?

Tags: php

Как прибавить или вычесть из time() секунды? Чтобы получить опять же timestamp

Comment: .

    $newTimestamp = time() - 3600;

Comment: Ааа...а как получить теперь из `$newTimestamp` минуты без ведущего нуля?

Comment: Кажется, так: `intval(date('i'), $newTimestamp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уважаемый, для этих целей есть мануал (все на русском) по данной функции: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

В вашем случае, чтобы отнять, надо:

```
$timestamp = time() - 3600;
```

Параметр:

```
G - Часы в 24-часовом формате без ведущего нуля
```

Comment: Я знаю, но в мануале минуты возвращаются с ведущим нулем.

Comment: Я так понимаю, в Вашем примере вы отнимаете от текущего времени 1 минуту.

Comment: Да отнимаем, я о печатался. Поправил текст сообщения.

Comment: Вам минуты или часы нужны без ведущего нуля?

Comment: Минуты без нуля

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, к своему удивлению не обнаружил получения даты в подобном формате. В принципе, можно поступить по-хакерски и просто вернуть `$newTimestamp % 60`. Насколько знаю, есть зоны, где смещение времени составляет Х.5 часов относительно UTC, и там этот хак будет выдавать ошибку в полчаса.

Ну и вами же описанный intval будет вполне себе работать, мне просто не очень нравится подход.